# How to set the android SDK path properly for IntellJ IDE community edition?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, flutter

I'm trying to use IntelliJ IDE to do some flutter programming.  I have the Android SDK in c:\Users\pam\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk and I have that same path showing in the Android SDK Location filed under System Settings > Android SDK.

But when I try to build a new flutter project (with the demo code that gets created), the build fails with the message "The SDK directory 'c:\Users\pam\IdeaProjects\flutter1\android\Users\pam\AppData\Local\Android\SDk' does not exit.  And that's right, it's not there, it's in the path I put into the IDE.

Anyone know how to fix this?  I'm pretty sure the location was chosen by android studio, but I don't really care where it lives as long as I can get some code to build.

Comment: you can see that Users\pam  is being called twice. I would first check why this happens.

Comment: also make sure that you don't mean 'Sdk' in your path instead of 'SDk'

Answer (score 0):

1) Download the flutter SDK from this link [flutter_windows_v0.4.4-beta.zip](https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/beta/windows/flutter_windows_v0.4.4-beta.zip)

2)Extract the zip-file and place the contained flutter in the desired installation location for the Flutter SDK (eg. C:\src\flutter; do not install flutter in a directory like C:\Program Files\ that requires elevated privileges).

For more information refer this link [Get Started with Flutter](https://flutter.io/setup-windows/#get-the-flutter-sdk)